# How to implement instanceof as a function receiving a string?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypejs, requirejs, circular-dependency

I'd like to get something like this

```
var isChild = isInstanceOf( var1, 'Constructor')
```

that should be equivalent to

```
var isChild = (var1 instanceof Constructor)
```

The thing is I do not have the function Constructor available in scope, so I'd like to just pass a string.

I guess I should traverse up the prototype chain in order to get the `constructor.toString()` and then compare it, but I don't quite know how to achieve it.

--

I will complete a little bit the context, mainly because I found a better solution

I had a circular reference between two function constructors, and RequireJS kept returning undefined when I tried to reference it. (In the case above, Constructor would be undefined.)

I found this piece of information: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

this is the code that caused the problem:

```
//(in BaseControl.js)

define(['src/utils/models/Field'], 
  function(Field) {
[...]

  setField: function(field) {

    if (!field instanceof Field) throw new Error('field should be an instance of Field');
    [...]
```

The problem is that Field also required BaseControl, so in this case Field was undefined, and I received the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got false
```

I could solve it following requireJS documentation:

```
define(['require', 'src/utils/models/Field'], 
  function(require, Field,) {
[...]

  setField: function(field) {

    if (!Field) Field = require('src/utils/models/Field');

    if (!field instanceof Field) throw new Error('field should be an instance of Field');
    [...]
```

Comment: oh, extra points for using ecma standard function (so I'd try to avoid __proto__ if possible...)

Comment: Why don't you have the construcor function in scope? In what scope is it then?

Comment: I'm working with requireJS, and if I require the Constructor I get a circular reference, so I'm looking for a way to validate the type of a parameter without requiring it.

Comment: What do you mean by "circular reference"? What would be wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest, Bergi. I had another look at the circular reference problem and solved it. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
function isInstanceOf(obj, constrname) {
    do {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "constructor")
          && typeof obj.constructor === "function"
          && obj.constructor.name == constrname )
            return true;
    } while (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))
    return false;
}
```

… using the non-standard [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) of named function objects.

---

However, this will not reliably work. Neither need are `name` properties supported by IE, nor will they work with anonymous functions (and those are common). So if you don't have the constructor against which you want to check around (for modularity or whatever reasons), you should try [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Have a look at http://zidan.me/javascript-interfaces/ as well. The `Interface` implementation can be found in the book *Pro JavaScript Design Patterns*, Chapter 2 *Interfaces* ([Google Books](http://books.google.de/books?id=za3vlnlWxb0C&lpg=PA14&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: ERROR : ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: @AbdennourToumi: No. Or: Where? You probably have a typo somewhere. Notice that the first equals signs are a strict comparison, the second a normal comparison and the last an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Under your auggestions above, I wrote the following short code, with related example:

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" TYPE="text/javascript">
function _check_data_type( _obj, _datatype )
{
    if ( _obj == null || _obj == "undefined" ) return -1 ;
    var _constructor = _obj.constructor + "" ;
    return ( typeof _obj === _datatype.toLowerCase() ||
             ( _constructor.toLowerCase().indexOf( _datatype.toLowerCase() ) != -1 ) ) ? 1 : 0 ;
}

    var _str1 = new String( "woow" );
    var _str2 = "woow" ;
    var _pi = 3.14 ;

    function myobj()
    {
        this.contents = "The apple is on the table" ;
    }

    var _array = new Array( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) ; 
    var _myobj = new myobj();

    document.write( "Casting the string 'woow' via object assignment: " + " >> " + ( _check_data_type( _str1, "string" ) ? "It's string" : "Not a string" ) + "<br>" ) ;
    document.write( "Casting the string 'woow' via literal assignment: " + " >> " + ( _check_data_type( _str2, "string" ) ? "It's string" : "Not a string" ) + "<br>" ) ;
    document.write( "is PI a number? " + " >> " + ( _check_data_type( _pi, "number" ) ? "Yes, it is" : "No !" ) + "<br>" ) ;
    document.write( "Is this an object of mine ? " + " >> " + ( _check_data_type( _myobj, "myobj" ) ? "Yes, it's yours, see contents : '" + _myobj.contents + "'" : "No !" ) + "<br>" ) ;
    document.write( "Is this an array obj? " + " >> " + ( _check_data_type( _array, "array" ) ? "Yes, it's an array" : "No !" ) + "<br>" ) ;
    </SCRIPT>
```